# typescript or basic OOP nested outcome

Tags: oop, typescript

I created two classes: hsClass and hsDeck:

```
export class hsClass {

    id:number;
    name:string;

    constructor(id:number,name:string)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

And

```
import {hsClass} from './hsClass';
export class hsDeck {

    id:number;
    name:string;
    hsClass:hsClass;

    constructor(id:number, name:string, hsClass:hsClass)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.hsClass = hsClass;
    }
}
```

So I tried to say "every hsDeck has its hsClass".

After instancing some:

```
export class hsDeckComponent {
    //Data-Bindings

    deckList: Array<hsDeck>;

    constructor(){

        let priestClass: hsClass = new hsClass(1,"priest");
        let shamanClass: hsClass = new hsClass(2,"shaman");

        this.deckList = [
            new hsDeck(1,"dragon priest",priestClass),
            new hsDeck(2,"reno priest",priestClass),
            new hsDeck(3,"aggro shaman",shamanClass),
            new hsDeck(4,"midrange jade shaman",shamanClass)
            ];
    }
}
```

The decklist Array works but is not what I tried to achieve.

What I am trying to achieve is an outcome (Data structure? Array?) grouped by hsClass. I want to have the hsDecks nested in hsClasses, if that makes any sense.

hsClass1

- hsDeck1
- hsDeck2

hsClass2

- hsDeck3
- hsDeck4

What's the best practice to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are storing the data not very suitably for your use case. You want each `hsClass` to "know" its `hsDeck` but you are specifiying which `hsDeck` has which `hsClass` (it is the other way around).

There are two ways of dealing with this.

1. You change the classes so that `hsClass` has a reference to `hsDeck`. This is the easier solution but is not desirable to have these two way dependencies because when the relationship changes, you need to update it in two places.
2. You compute the structure you need dynamically when you need it.

You could achieve the second way using [lodash](https://lodash.com/) like so:

```
const classDecks = _.groupBy(this.deckList, ((deck: hsDeck): number => deck.hsClass.id));

// returns something like { 1: [dragon priest deck, reno priest deck], 2: [aggro shaman deck, midrange jade shaman deck ] }
```